# Loop through JSON in JS

Tags: javascript, json, loops

I have a json file and need to access/loop some properties.

With the code below, I only receive "*Object {dish: Array[1], price: Array[1], restaurant: Array[1]}*" in my Console instead of all 162 elements inside the group array.

To be specific on what I need: I want to print out each DISH, PRICE, RESTAURANT property inside the group array!

My JS looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function update() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        for(var i=0; i< jsonData.result.extractorData.data[0].group.length; i+=1) {
          var statusHTML = jsonData.result.extractorData.data[0].group[i];
        }
        console.log(statusHTML);
         statusHTML += '</ul>';
         document.getElementById('ajax').innerHTML = statusHTML;
       }
    };

    xhr.open('GET', 'data/restaurantquery.json');

    xhr.send();
    setTimeout(update, 5000);
});
```

My json looks like:

```
{
"extractorData": {
    "url": "www.site.com",
    "resourceId": "myid",
    "data": [{
        "group": [{
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Panini Caprese"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "3,60 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Deine Rezept Galerie"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Reisgericht"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Eat Drink Man Woman"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Chicken Curry"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "La Bamboo"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Flammkuchen Bruschetta"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "5,00 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Deine Rezept Galerie"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Gyros"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Taverne Diogenes"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Mittagessen"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Ceylonas Restaurant"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Mittagessen vegetarisch"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,00 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Ceylonas Restaurant"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Cornflakesschnitzel von der Pute"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "8,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Zadu Cafe & Restaurant"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Tagliatelle"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Cafe Chiquilin"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Fischfilet paniert"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Der Metzger Schneider"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Zigeuner Gulasch"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "5,80 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Der Metzger Schneider"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Kartoffel-Lauch-Gratin"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Cafe Chiquilin"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Kartoffelsuppe"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Augustin"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Kresse Rahmsuppe"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "4,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Feinkosterei Weller"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "SÃ¼ÃŸkartoffel-Birnen-Sambal Oelek-Creme Suppe"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "4,20 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Lumen"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Asiatischer Glasnudelsalat"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Lumen"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Nudeln"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "La Piccola Napoli"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Aubergine"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,30 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Sultan Saray"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Gemischtes GemÃ¼se"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Sultan Saray"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Ratatouille-Quiche"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "8,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Restaurant LÃ¤ssig"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Calamares"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,95 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "AllgÃ¤uer StÃ¼ble"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Forellenfilet"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,40 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Alte Wache"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Frisches Seelachsfilet paniert"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "8,95 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "AllgÃ¤uer StÃ¼ble"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Lachs"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "8,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "La Piccola Napoli"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Lachsfilet gerollt"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Sultan Saray"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Paniertes Fischfilet"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Feinkosterei Weller"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Pasta Frutti di Mare"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,70 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Lumen"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Schollen-SpinatrÃ¶llchen"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "12,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Restaurant LÃ¤ssig"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "\"Hawaii Burger\" 180 Gr Rinderhack belegt"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,60 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Wirtshaus zum Hotzenplotz"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Farfalle Bolognese"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "4,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Il Pomodoro"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Thai-Fleischpfanne"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "5,99 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Naturgut HÃ¶lderlinplatz"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "HÃ¤hnchenschenkel"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,40 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Wohnzimmer"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Paniertes HÃ¼hnerfleisch"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "5,00 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Lin's Wok"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Sesam SemmelknÃ¶del"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Lumen"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Kartoffelsahnegratin"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,00 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Feinkosterei Weller"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Zucchini-Eintopf"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "4,99 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Naturgut HÃ¶lderlinplatz"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Wokgericht"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Feinkosterei Weller"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Rinderschmorbraten"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "8,30 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Lumen"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "GemÃ¼se-Minestrone"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "4,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Cafe Chiquilin"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Gebratene Nudeln"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Kwan Kao"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "FrÃ¼hlingssalat"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Cafe Chiquilin"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Hausgemachter Hamburger"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,80 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Cafe Chiquilin"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Ente gebraten"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Kwan Kao"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "HÃ¤hnchen"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Kwan Kao"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Tofu gebraten"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Kwan Kao"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "FlÃ¤dlesuppe"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "3,80 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Wohnzimmer"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "GrÃ¼nkohlsuppe"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Bella Italia Weine"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Hausgemachte Kartoffelsuppe"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "4,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Sutsche"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Kartoffelsuppe"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "4,80 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Lichtblick"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Minestrone vom Rind"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "4,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Ampulle"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Bavette"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "9,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Bella Italia Weine"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Kurze Nudeln"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,00 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Ristorante Cavallino"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Lange Nudeln"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "8,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Ristorante Cavallino"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Pasta Napoli"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Lichtblick"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Pasta Pomodoro"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Zadu Cafe & Restaurant"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Penne"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "9,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Bella Italia Weine"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Rigatoni \"Syrakusa\""
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Rote Kapelle"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Schinkennudeln"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,80 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Sutsche"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Schinkennudeln"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,20 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Lichtblick"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Spiral-Nudeln"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "8,00 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Ristorante Cavallino"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Gnocchi"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "8,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Ampulle"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Pizza nach Wahl"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "8,00 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Ristorante Cavallino"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Pizza nach Wahl"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "La Piccola Napoli"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Blattsalate"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "8,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Wohnzimmer"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Bunter gemischter Salatteller"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,20 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Lichtblick"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Bunter Salatteller"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Zadu Cafe & Restaurant"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Bunter Salatteller"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Lichtblick"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Bunter Salatteller"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "8,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Lichtblick"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Bunter Salatteller"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "8,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Lichtblick"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Gemischter Salat"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Sutsche"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Gemischter Salat"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Sutsche"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Gemischter Salat"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Sutsche"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Gemischter Salat"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,00 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Rote Kapelle"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Gemischter Salat"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,00 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Rote Kapelle"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "GroÃŸer gemischter Salat"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "8,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Ristorante Cavallino"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Rucola-Eissalat"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "12,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Ampulle"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Salat"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "8,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Bella Italia Weine"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Sommerlicher Salat"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,00 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Rote Kapelle"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Auberginen Ã¼berbacken"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,60 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Sutsche"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "GemÃ¼serolle SÃ¼ÃŸ/sauer/scharf"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "8,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Restaurant RÃ¶sch"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Chilli con Carne"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Rote Kapelle"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Gegrillter PutenbrustspieÃŸ"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "8,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Ampulle"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Geschmorte HÃ¤hnchenschenkel"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "9,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Ampulle"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Puten-Gyros"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "8,20 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Lichtblick"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Putenbrust-Filet"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "9,00 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Ristorante Cavallino"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Putenschaschlik"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,80 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Sutsche"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Ein paniertes Schnitzel vom Schwein"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Lichtblick"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Rahm-Schnitzel"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,95 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "AllgÃ¤uer StÃ¼ble"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Schnitzel \"Wienerart\" vom schwÃ¤bisch HÃ¤llischem SchweinerÃ¼cken"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,40 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Alte Wache"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Schweineschnitzel-Putenschnitzel paniert"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "5,95 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "AllgÃ¤uer StÃ¼ble"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Vegetarisches Schnitzel oder Cordon Bleu"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "AllgÃ¤uer StÃ¼ble"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Spinat-Tortellini"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,40 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Alte Wache"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Tortellini"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Ampulle"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Hausgemachte KÃ¤sspÃ¤tzle"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,40 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Sutsche"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "KÃ¤s'spÃ¤tzle"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "8,20 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Lichtblick"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "SpÃ¤tzlepfanne"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Lichtblick"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "RinderbÃ¤ckchen"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "12,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Wohnzimmer"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Steak Frites"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "8,00 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Rote Kapelle"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Steak vom Grill"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "14,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Bella Italia Weine"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Falafel"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Rote Kapelle"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Frischer Obstsalat"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "4,00 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Rote Kapelle"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "GemÃ¼seauflauf"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,20 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Sutsche"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Kartoffel-Lauch-Gratin"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Lichtblick"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Kartoffelgratin"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Zadu Cafe & Restaurant"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Glas Sekt"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "4,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Wohnzimmer"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Linsen"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,40 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Sutsche"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Linsen"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "8,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Lichtblick"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Mexikanische Linsensuppe"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "4,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Rote Kapelle"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Eine geschmÃ¤lzte Maultasche"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "8,20 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Lichtblick"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "GerÃ¶stete Maultaschen"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Zadu Cafe & Restaurant"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "GerÃ¶stete Maultaschen"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,10 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Sutsche"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Hausgemachte Maultaschen geschmelzt"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,60 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Sutsche"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Hot Wok"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Rote Kapelle"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Fischfilet WeiÃŸweinsoÃŸe GemÃ¼seblÃ¤ttchen"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "9,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Restaurant RÃ¶sch"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "FleischkÃ¼chle"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "8,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Restaurant RÃ¶sch"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Linseneintopf"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "8,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Restaurant RÃ¶sch"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Maultaschen"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "10,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Restaurant RÃ¶sch"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Gebratene Reisnudeln"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Pho Viet"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Gebratenes Reisnudeln"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Eat Drink Man Woman"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Nudelgericht"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Eat Drink Man Woman"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Gemischter Salat"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Taverne Diogenes"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Gemischter Salat"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "9,00 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Taverne Diogenes"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Oktopus-Salat"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "12,00 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Taverne Diogenes"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "GemÃ¼se Curry"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "5,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "La Bamboo"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Omlett"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,00 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Taverne Diogenes"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Panini Parma"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "4,00 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Deine Rezept Galerie"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Vegetarisches Kottu Rotti"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "5,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "La Bamboo"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Moussaka"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "9,00 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Taverne Diogenes"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Omlett"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,00 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Taverne Diogenes"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Mittagessen"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Ceylonas Restaurant"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Mittagessen"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Ceylonas Restaurant"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Pangasius Filet"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "9,00 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Taverne Diogenes"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Saganaki"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "12,00 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Taverne Diogenes"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Saganaki"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "9,00 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Taverne Diogenes"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Bifteki"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "9,00 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Taverne Diogenes"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Rindfleisch"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "8,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "La Bamboo"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Rumpsteak"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "12,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Taverne Diogenes"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Souvlaki"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "7,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Taverne Diogenes"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Chicken"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "8,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "La Bamboo"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Gebratene Reis"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Eat Drink Man Woman"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Im Wok geschwenktes Huhn"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Pho Viet"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Im Wok geschwenktes Huhn"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Pho Viet"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Im Wok geschwenktes Huhn"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Pho Viet"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Im Wok geschwenktes Huhn"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Pho Viet"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Im Wok geschwenktes Huhn"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Pho Viet"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Im Wok geschwenktes Huhn"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Pho Viet"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Mittagessen"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Ceylonas Restaurant"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Schnitzel"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "La Bamboo"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Schnitzel paniert"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Taverne Diogenes"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Mittagessen"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,90 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Ceylonas Restaurant"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Flammkuchen Klassisch"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "5,00 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Deine Rezept Galerie"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Flammkuchen sÃ¼ÃŸ"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "4,50 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Deine Rezept Galerie"
            }]
        }, {
            "dish": [{
                "text": "Flammkuchen ZiegenkÃ¤se"
            }],
            "price": [{
                "text": "6,00 â‚¬"
            }],
            "restaurant": [{
                "text": "Deine Rezept Galerie"
            }]
        }]
    }]
},
"pageData": {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "timestamp": 1460111085461
}
}
```

Comment: Walk through your code in the debugger paying special attention to the value of `statusHTML` at every point.

Comment: This long JSON isn't the shortest way to reproduce the issue, so this question lacks [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You're always assigning `statusHTML` to the current iteration of the loop, and never concatenate the results. Change it to something like this:

```
var statusHTML = "";
for(var i=0; i< jsonData.result.extractorData.data[0].group.length; i+=1) {
   statusHTML += jsonData.result.extractorData.data[0].group[i];
}
console.log(statusHTML);
statusHTML += '</ul>';
document.getElementById('ajax').innerHTML = statusHTML;
```

If you just use `=` to assign to `statusHTML` every time, you will always get the last iteration.
If you wanted to have each element in its own `li`it would be something like this:

```
var statusHTML = "";
for(var i=0; i< jsonData.result.extractorData.data[0].group.length; i+=1) {
   statusHTML += "<li>";
   statusHTML += jsonData.result.extractorData.data[0].group[i];
   statusHTML += "</li>";
}
console.log(statusHTML);
statusHTML += '</ul>';
document.getElementById('ajax').innerHTML = statusHTML;
```

Comment: Great!Thank you for your hint.